# Replace c# ошибка с кавычками

Tags: c#

Есть код замены

```
string  c1 = "{"vrastgood":", c2 = "";
textBox2.Text = html.Replace(c1, c2);
```

Но он не правильный в этой части:

```
"{"vrastgood":"
```

Я знаю что в "" заключается то что нужно заменить, но как действовать в случае если нужно заменить и "

Comment: ничего не понял. Что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Похоже, вам нужно "экранировать" кавычки: `c1 = "{\"vrastgood\":";`

Comment: или можете использовать @"...."

Comment: Для @"..." всеравно нужно экранировать кавычки, только там это делается так:  `@"{""vrastgood"":"`

Answer (score 1):

Выбирай:

```
string c1 = "{\"vrastgood\":", c2 = "";
textBox2.Text = html.Replace(c1, c2);
```

```
string c1 = @"{""vrastgood"":", c2 = "";
textBox2.Text = html.Replace(c1, c2);
```

Comment: ТС явно пытается парсить JSON.